# Windows server how to send a HTTP delete method

Tags: curl, couchbase, windows-server, http-delete, http-method

I am working with Couchbase, and I want to delete a bucket.

According to the [official page](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-bucket-delete.html)
I should do this:

> To delete buckets, use the DELETE /pools/default/buckets/[bucket-name] HTTP method and URI.

I am working on Windows server 2012 and this is what I did:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>curl -X DELETE "/pools/default/buckets/gamesim-sample"
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

and as you see, I got the  error shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a URL, have you tried adding `http://localhost:port` to it?

Comment: in this case, i got nothing, but according to couchbase i should get 200 response. please could you give me tutorial about how to make a http method

Comment: On the page that you have linked the syntax is `curl -u [admin]:[password]
http://[localhost]:8091//pools/default/buckets/[bucket-name]`, but I think that the double slash after the port number is a typo, it should be single. Note that in the example they aren't using the -X argument: `curl -u Administrator:password
http://10.5.2.54:8091/pools/default/buckets/myTestBucket`, so you should remove it. Alternatively you can try to send a raw HTTP request, but I would stick with curl. If you still have problems you could try wget too

Comment: that double slash was a typo in the question, i do this now `C:\Users\Administrator>curl -u administrator:mypassword  -DELETE http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/gamesim-sample` and i got empty results (i mean nothing is being on the cmd and the bucket didn't delete), the thing is that no one is helping here, please help

Comment: No one is helping you? So I should stop helping? It's not polite speaking like this when someone is trying to help you. Anyway the example is very clear, you should type `curl -u Administrator:password
http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/gamesim-sample` without the `-X DELETE`

Comment: i tried your solution, but also i got empty results, however, when i tried to put a wrong password or a wrong ip address, i got error states that the thing is wrong, maybe that website is putting the example for linux, i don't know, i tried with and without -x delete. i meant bty that no body else is helping, just my english is not recognize

Comment: You wrote `curl -u administrator:mypassword -DELETE http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/gamesim-sample`, but it should be `curl -u administrator:mypassword -X DELETE http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets/gamesim-sample`

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the `"` characters.

Comment: the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell in Windows 10, the below command did the trick.

```
curl -Method Delete http://localhost:port/id
```

Note:- id refers to the id of whatever the JSON data you want to be deleted